# android- Cancelling ongoing IntentService download by breaking the while loop with Broadcast

Tags: android, android-intentservice, android-broadcastreceiver

I'm using IntentService to download files from url, using the following code:

```
    package com.example.myapp;

    import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
    import java.io.File;
    import java.io.FileOutputStream;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.io.InputStream;
    import java.net.URL;
    import java.net.URLConnection;

    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.app.IntentService;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.os.Environment;
    import android.util.Log;

    public class DownloadService extends IntentService {

        private int result = Activity.RESULT_CANCELED;
        public static final String URL = "urlpath";
        public static final String FILENAME = "filename";
        public static final String DOWNLOAD_POSITION = "position";
        public static final String FILEPATH = "filepath";
        public static final String RESULT = "result";
        public static final String PERCENTAGE = "PERCENTAGE";
        public static final String FILE_SIZE = "FILESIZE";
        public static final String NOTIFICATION = "service receiver";
        public static BufferedInputStream bis;
        public static long lengthofFile;
        public int dnlPosition;
        public String fileName;
        public DownloadService() {
            super("DownloadService");
        }

        @Override
        protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
            String urlPath = intent.getStringExtra(URL);
            fileName = intent.getStringExtra(FILENAME);
            dnlPosition = intent.getIntExtra("downloadPosition", 0);
            File output = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS),
                    fileName);
            if (output.exists()) {
                output.delete();
            }

            URLConnection streamConnection = null;
            InputStream stream = null;
            FileOutputStream fos = null;
            try {

                URL url = new URL(urlPath);
                streamConnection = url.openConnection();
                stream = streamConnection.getInputStream();
                streamConnection.connect();
                lengthofFile = streamConnection.getContentLength();
                String fileSize = Long.toString(lengthofFile);
                InputStream reader = stream;

                bis = new BufferedInputStream(reader);
                fos = new FileOutputStream(output.getPath());
                int next = -1;
                int progress = 0;
                int bytesRead = 0;
                byte buffer[] = new byte[1024];

                while ((bytesRead = bis.read(buffer)) > 0) {
                    fos.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
                    progress += bytesRead;
                    int progressUpdate = (int)((progress * 100) / lengthofFile);
                    Intent testIntent = new Intent("com.example.myapp.MESSAGE_INTENT");
                    testIntent.putExtra(PERCENTAGE, progressUpdate);
                    testIntent.putExtra(FILE_SIZE, lengthofFile);
                    testIntent.putExtra(DOWNLOAD_POSITION, dnlPosition);
                    testIntent.putExtra(FILENAME, fileName);
                    sendBroadcast(testIntent);
                }
                result = Activity.RESULT_OK;
                fos.flush();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                if (stream != null) {
                    try {
                        stream.close();
                        bis.close();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
                if (fos != null) {
                    try {
                        fos.close();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
            publishResults(output.getAbsolutePath(), result);
        }
    }
```

it works fine as it is, however if I wanted to cancel an ongoing download, or one of the queued files, i'm still stuck on this step, 
I was thinking that i can send a broadcast on cancel button click where the service will listen to it and if the broadcast says break the `while ((bytesRead = bis.read(buffer)) > 0)` loop it breaks it.

Is this scenario even possible?

Regards

Comment: I believe you'll have to come up with your own implementation, creating and managing the asynchronous file transfer from your service so that the service itself stays responsive to react to cancel requests.

Comment: Might want to have a look at [`ExecutorService`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html). Note that this is *not* related to an Android `Service` in any way! It's just a coincidental naming collision.